# Loopback User model with PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback

I am facing error in posting my code over postgresql database using loopback via api explorer.
below is my consumer.json

```
{
  "name": "consumer",
  "plural": "consumers",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id":{
      "type":"number",
      "required":true,
      "id":true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

my model-config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "practise"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": false,
    "relations": {
      "user": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "person",
        "foreignKey": "id"
      }
    }
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": false,
    "options": {
      "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
    }
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": false
  },
  "person": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": true
  },
  "customer": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": true
  },
  "customuser": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": true
  },
  "consumer": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": true
  },
  "priority": {
    "dataSource": "practise",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
{   "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "error",
    "message": "column \"id\" does not exist",
    "length": 164,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42703",
    "position": "8",
    "file": "d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\parser\\parse_relation.c",
    "line": "3359",
    "routine": "errorMissingColumn",
    "stack": "error: column \"id\" does not exist\n    at Connection.parseE (D:\\Users\\Yesha.Bhatt\\Documents\\authpractise\\node_modules\\pg\\lib\\connection.js:614:13)\n at Connection.parseMessage (D:\\Users\\Yesha.Bhatt\\Documents\\authpractise\\node_modules\\pg\\lib\\connection.js:413:19)\n at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\\Users\\Yesha.Bhatt\\Documents\\authpractise\\node_modules\\pg\\lib\\connection.js:129:22)\n at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)\n    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)\n    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)"   } }
```

I have id as the column in my PostgreSQL DB too. The error keeps varying but I am not able to post the data using PostgreSQL over the database.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, You are using loopbackv3,
There may be some problem with your schema, You once crosscheck schema or you can paste it here.